# HDD not detected in BIOS but is detected by Windows?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a WD Gold 10TB HDD, that I plugged into a new build and it is not showing up in BIOS, yet Disk Management detects it and wants to initialize it, with a error:

> "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error."

From what I remember, this drive should already be initialized and already have a created partion, even with a BitLocker encryption enabled.

CrystalDiskInfo detects the drive as well, so does the R-Studio I tried to open up.

- OS: Windows 11 Pro
- Motherboard: MSI PRO Z690-A WIFI
- HDD: WD Gold 10TB WD102KRYZ

Already tried changing SATA ports. Right now its on SATA Port 02. Power is going to it. Its connected on the first power connector and on the last one is functioning old WD Black 1TB.

Can I somehow save this drive and connect to it?

Comment: `The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.` is that stated exactly so? Asking because that would be an `I/O device` error, not within the HDD, which should be stated as `device I/O` error. This kind of mismatches can lead your answer astray.

Comment: Do you need to save data from the disk. or just to use it? Is the disk still under warranty?

Comment: If you're using CrystalDiskImnfo then how hard is it to post the screenshot of SMART values as well?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I somehow save this drive and connect to it?

The question implies that your drive is the problem.

As it appears very contradictory that your Windows disk management is facing poblems with this drive but applications do not, I would recommened excluding other error sources by

1. connecting the drive to a different machine
2. use a different connection type such as UBS 3.0 when putting the drive into an external enclosure or docking station

but the most important source of information is self-diagnosis based on SMART data. You should post a complete SMART report running Smartmontools which runs under Windows and linux.

`sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdx > myreport.txt`

Replace the "x" in "sdx" by the drive letter (a small letter!) of your HDD in question.

You find a little summary of how to use smartmontools here:

https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10910